# Bintray SAML Authentication

Tags: saml, bintray

I work for an org that uses Bintray's Pro plan and am trying to enable SAML Authentication for the organisation? According to this doc there is a enable SAML Authentication button which I can't seem to locate https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Configuring+Google+as+Your+SAML+Provider

Also can we have username/pass login for existing users & SAML auth for others that sign up from now or is it just all SAML and we re auth everyone?

Thank you in advance

Cheers
Josh

Answer (score 0):

The SAML authentication feature is not available for Bintray Pro plan and available only for the Bintray Enterprise Plan.

If you have enabled SAML feature to your Bintray account in future, there won't be any restrictions to access your Bintray account just by the SAML. You can continue to access your Bintray account with the already existing authentication methods along with the SAML.